# How to use "become_pass" in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-vault

I try to write an Ansible yml that reads the root-passwords from an encrypted vault-file and then pass it to become_pass:

```
    - hosts: sirius
      remote_user: ansusr
      become: yes
      vars_files:
         - vault_vars.yml
      become_pass: "{{ root_pass_sirius }}"
```

But this fails:
ERROR! 'become_pass' is not a valid attribute for a Play

But why ? - According to the Ansible documentation this is a valid command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> According to the Ansible documentation this is a valid command.

Wrong. `become_pass` is not a valid attribute (and it is not a *command* after all) for a Play.

Please see [List of Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters). There is `ansible_become_pass` variable.

So you need to set a variable:

```
- hosts: sirius
  remote_user: ansusr
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vault_vars.yml
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ root_pass_sirius }}"
```

Comment: That doesn't work either ... ERROR! 'ansible_become_pass' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Comment: Hm ... seems I had som tailing invisible character ... it works now! - Thanks a lot